# How to write query spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have classe notification has attribut receiver with type User like this :

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "sender", referencedColumnName = "id")
@JsonIgnore
private User sender;
```

and user has attribut bed :

```
@ManyToOne
        (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "idBed")
@JsonIgnore
private Bed idBed;
```

and bed has attribut room :

```
  @ManyToOne
            (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "idroom")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Room room;
```

and room has attribut :

```
@ManyToOne
        (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "idCarePost")
@JsonIgnore
private CarePost carePost;
```

please need to read all this data please how can i do it ?

Comment: maybe have a look at `JPARepository` and "native query"

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPARepository. It will give the CRUD features out of the box you don't need to write any query. For example, if you use the save(object) method in the service class it will save the object no need to write the insert query.

If you want to write your custom query in the repository you can write by using @Query("write your custom query", nativeQuery = true) annotation.

```
@Repository
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {
@Query(value = "select * from posts p where p.author like %:value%", nativeQuery = true)
List<Post> findByAuthor(String value);
}
```

The above example is a way to write a native query using JPARepository.

Comment: I have 4 tables related , how i can get it without query ?

Comment: you are using ORM mapping so many beds are in one room and many rooms are in carePost like this first you put the bed object to the room object and then put the room object to the carePost object and at last you save the carePost object it will save all the object related to the carePost.

Comment: for saving i did it, but now i'm reading i need to read all this data bed , room, carepost, related to the notification who has his sender , who has firs his bed and the bed has his room and the room has his carepost, i failed to read them

Comment: then you just fire a native query as I mention above and you can get the related all data at once.

Comment: @Query(value="Select  u , n , b , c  " + "FROM users u, notification n , bed b, room r, carepost c " +
            " INNER JOIN users u on u.id  = n.sender" +
            " INNER JOIN bed b  on u.idBed =b.idBed " +
            "INNER JOIN room r on r.idroom =b.idroom " +
            "INNER JOIN carepost c on c.idCarePost =r.idCarePost "
          , nativeQuery = true)

Answer (score 0):

You have jpa repository method as below.

Find user by some attribute as below.

```
List<User> findByName();
```

Find user by bed as below.

```
List<User> findByBed( bed object);
```

Find user by  with continue object.

```
List<User> findByBedRoomCarePostName(string 
carePostName);
```

Comment: I need notification , who has user(is the sender of the notification ) and the user has  the bed and the bed has the room and the room has the carePost

Comment: can't do findByBedRoomCarePost !

Comment: Try as findByBed_Room_CarePost()

Comment: Failed can't access to  them throw notification !